# Minimum length of n-dimensional cubes to cover k points

Tags: algorithm, 3d

let's assume that we have k points having n coordinates.

```
 (a11, a12, a13, ...., a1n)

 (a21, a22, a23, ...., a2n)

 .
 .

 (ak1, ak2, ak3, ...., akn)
```

and we're allowed to use x number of n-dimensional cubes to cover those points

(if the points are on the cube, like they are on the surface or side or vertice of the cube, or inside the cube, then we consider the point to be covered by the cube).

If k and x are fixed, and all cubes must have the same side length, can we figure out 
what would be the minimum side length of squares, so that they cover all the points?
Cubes can overlap, and they must be parallel to the coordinate axes.

For instance, let's n=2, and k=5, x=2, and the points are 
(2, 0), (0, 4), (2, 2), (3, 2), (0, 8), then the minimum side length of the cubes 
should be 4, and the cube with vertices (0, 0), (0, 4), (4, 0), (4, 4) and 
one with vertices (4, 0), (4, 4), (8, 4), (8, 0) would cover all the points

I was wondering if there was a way to do it. For n=1, it's pretty trivial, and 
if there are well-known algorithms for n=2, n=3 cases, maybe we could extend 
from them.

Comment: should those 'cubes' have sides parallel to coord axises?

Comment: Herokiller   sorry I forgot to add that. I edited my question.